# MySQL interface with copy/paste functionality and conditional formatting

Tags: database, mysql, microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, microsoft-access

I am looking for a MySQL UI with some spreadsheet-like features.

We need:

1. Copy & paste functionality
2. Conditional formatting

I have tested a lot of tools and have not found exactly what we need.

Table Plus is great. It's the closest thing I've found. It allows you to copy and paste rows, then click save to run the insert queries.

I've also tried AppSheets and Retool. They are powerful and can connect directly to MySQL. You can add conditional formatting and other automations which are nice. But the copy & paste functionality is missing.

On Retool's forum someone requested this copy & paste feature. Unfortunately, Retool just suggested a work around.

We need a single central database that multiple people can work on at once. So local Excel does not work.

We currently use Excel with collaborative co-authoring. Then we import the spreadsheet into a MySQL database. This partially works, but our data is getting too large for hosted Excel and we need strong typing and other features that a relational database provides.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [FileMaker](https://www.claris.com/filemaker/).

You can easily [connect](https://discoverfilemaker.com/install-mysql-odbc-drivers-connect-filemaker-15-mysql/) it to your current MySQL database.

This way you can create a GUI for you and your colleagues and edit that not through Excel but to something more professional.

Comment: This does not support the first feature I said we need. Does not support copy & pasting rows like excel.

Comment: @AlanReed, yes, it supports copy/paste: https://help.claris.com/en/pro-help/content/copying-moving-data.html#:~:text=Select%20the%20contents%20of%20the,then%20choose%20Edit%20menu%20%3E%20Paste.